# How to convert this anonymous class into named inner class

Tags: java

I couldn't find any examples like it. I want to convert this anonymous Java class into named inner class.

```
public class AnonymousInnerClassExercise{

    public class AnonymousInnerClassExercise{
      public AnonymousInnerClassExercise() {
          Frame frame = new Frame();
          frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
              public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                  System.exit(0);
              }
          });
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Amartaivan, try to do this on your own first then we can help if you run into problems. A lot of programming is about rigorous trial and error, you have to pick up this skill instead of copying from examples. Make sure you’re using a Java IDE such as IDEA, Eclipse, or VSCode

Comment: Ok. It should start `public class MyNamedInnerClass extends WindowAdapter` - good luck!

Comment: ^^ Yes and simply implement the single method in that class.

Comment: Check http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/extendsWindowAdapter.htm

Comment: Thank you guys, it helps

Comment: `public class AnonymousInnerClassExercise{ public class AnonymousInnerClassExercise{ ...` - not sure if that is so good:  a class named `A` inside another class also named `A`

Comment: You should call it anonymous class, not to be confused with inner classes.